# Weird type deduction using constexpr + auto as return and parameter type

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, c++20

I've been playing with compiler optimizations and compiler explorer and have noticed the following shortcoming in g++ 9.3 (tested locally). The issue seems to persist in g++ 10.1 (tested on compiler explorer). I am using the

Note the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr auto fib( auto x )
{
    if( x == 0 )
        return 0;
    else if( x == 1 )
        return 1;
    else
        return fib( x - 1 ) + fib( x - 2 );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::cerr << std::setprecision(10) << fib( 47.l );
}
```

Compiler explorer link [here](https://godbolt.org/z/uNGTeW).

I understand that if I had put 47, template argument deduction would have deduced the function `int foo( int x )`, but this persists even when I pass a long double literal.

This leads to overflow.

Why can't the compiler deduce at compile time that my return type should be a double? I would have expected that, as fib is marked constexpr, and I am compiling with -O3, that even if I had passed an integer, g++ would be able to deduce that a double was required by realising that fib was exponential.

Even if the above is prohibitively hard, why does passing in a long double literal not fix the problem? I would expect the function to realise that the third branch of the function must return a long double, so the return type should be a long double.

The compiler only realises a long double is required when fib is changed to return 0.l and 1.l like so:

```cpp
constexpr auto fib( auto x )
{
    if( x == 0 )
        return 0.l;
    else if( x == 1 )
        return 1.l;
    else
        return fib( x - 1 ) + fib( x - 2 );
}
```

Interestingly, changing only one of the returns to a long double literal like so:

```cpp
    if( x == 0 )
        return 0.l;
    else if( x == 1 )
        return 1;
```

Results in the following error:

```
error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: ‘long double’ and then ‘int’
```

How can this throw an error but the first example not?

Comment: The deduce return type depends *only* on the return statements in the function, not on the argument type passed in.

Comment: Just because your function parameters are doubles doesn't mean that functions will return doubles. The only thing the function returns is either 0 or 1, so it must be int, and this is consistent with returning the result of the addition to int and int, which is int. Therefore the function returns an int no matter what its parameter is.

Comment: "g++ would be able to deduce that a double was required by realising that fib was exponential" - that's not how `auto` (or template type deduction) works. You specify the types (sometimes indirectly), the compiler applies them. It is not allowed to choose arbitrarily based on how it thinks you might use a function.

Comment: I would LOVE a telepathic compiler. Programs that did what I wanted instead of what I told them to do would make my life whole orders of magnitude easier. But I'd have to remove the Terminator soundtrack from my playlist.That could end badly.

Comment: compiler explorer tells me that the function signature is int fib int. I now understand why the return type is an int, but why is the parameter type also int?

Comment: Also, why is the type deduction I initially expected not possible? It seems like it would make life easier

Comment: The parameter is not "deduced" to be of type ```int```, try calling in ```fib(47.1l)``` and see what happens

Answer (score 7):

When you define a function like this:

```
constexpr auto f(auto x) 
{
  return 42;
}
```

the compiler has *no choice* but to deduce the return type as `int`, because that's the type of the literal `42`. It doesn't matter if you call `f` with an argument of some other type:

```
f(42.l);
```

the return type is still `int`, although the type of `x` is `long double`.

However, you can explicitly ask for the return type to be the same as the argument type:

```
constexpr auto f(auto x) -> decltype(x)
{
  return 42;
}
```

and now the return value will be converted to the type of the argument that `f` is called with.